# AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication when using Node.js webdriver.io on AWS Device Farm

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I have successfully ran the tests on Android devices. But still struggling with iOS.
Locally it all runs fine, but on AWS it just wont launch the app.
I can see the being installed, but wont launch
I have added all the relevant code on this gist https://gist.github.com/cescoferraro/2196382c88f6c0c50bd8f2f16cf4fb61

```
const awsopts = {
    path: '/wd/hub',
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        automationName: "XCUITest",
        platformName: process.env.DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME,
        udid: "auto",
        app: process.env.DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH,
    },
};
```

Definitions

```
version: 0.1

# Phases are collection of commands that get executed on Device Farm.
phases:
  # The install phase includes commands that install dependencies that your tests use.
  # Default dependencies for testing frameworks supported on Device Farm are already installed.
  install:
    commands:
      # This test execution environment uses Appium version 1.7.2 by default, however we enable you to change it using the Appium version manager (avm)
      # An example "avm" command below changes the version to 1.14.2
      # For your convenience, we have preinstalled the following versions: 1.9.1, 1.10.1, 1.11.1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.15.1, 1.16.0, and 1.17.1
      # For iOS devices on OS version 13.4 and above, please use Appium version 1.17.1 for the best possible experience
      # Additionally, for iOS devices on OS version 13.0 through 13.3, please use Appium version 1.16.0 or higher
      # To use one of these Appium versions, change the version number in the "avm" command below to your desired version:
      - export APPIUM_VERSION=1.14.2
      - avm $APPIUM_VERSION
      - ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium  /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js

      # Device farm provides 4 different pre-built versions of WebDriverAgent, and each is suggested for different versions of Appium:
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V4: this version is suggested for Appium 1.17.1. V4 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases/tag/v2.14.1
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V3: this version is suggested for Appium 1.16.0. V3 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases/tag/v2.3.2
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V2: this version is suggested for Appium 1.15.1. V2 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/tree/v1.3.5
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1: this version is suggested for Appium 1.9.1 through 1.14.2. V1 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/tree/2dbbf917ec2e4707bae9260f701d43c82b55e1b9
      # We will automatically configure your WebDriverAgent version based on your Appium version using the following code.

      # For users of Appium versions 1.15.0 and higher, your Appium version requires that your UDID of the device not contain any "-" characters
      # So, we will create a new environment variable of your UDID specifically for Appium based on your Appium version
      - >-
        if [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 17 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V4;
        elif [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 16 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V3;
        elif [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 15 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V2;
        else
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID;
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1;
        fi

      # By default the node version installed is 10.9.0
      # you can switch to an alternate node version using below command.
      - nvm install 14.9.0

      # Unpackage and install the node modules that you uploaded in the test phase.
      - echo "Navigate to test package directory"
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - npm install *.tgz

  # The pre-test phase includes commands that setup your test environment.
  pre_test:
    commands:
      # We recommend starting appium server process in the background using the command below.
      # Appium server log will go to $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR directory.
      # The environment variables below will be auto-populated during run time.
      - echo "Start appium server"
      - >-
        appium --log-timestamp
        --default-capabilities "{\"usePrebuiltWDA\": true, \"derivedDataPath\":\"$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH\",
        \"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\", \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\",
        \"automationName\":\"XCUITest\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\"}"
        >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &

      - >-
        start_appium_timeout=0;
        while [ true ];
        do
            if [ $start_appium_timeout -gt 60 ];
            then
                echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
                exit 1;
            fi;
            grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then
                echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
                break;
            else
                echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
                sleep 1;
                start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
            fi;
        done;

  # The test phase includes commands that start your test suite execution.
  test:
    commands:
      # Your test package is downloaded in $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      # However, we must navigate to its subdirectory "node_modules/*", as this directory has your test code and dependency node modules
      - echo "Navigate to test code directory"
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH/node_modules/*

      - echo "Start Appium Node test"
      # Enter the command below to start the tests . The comamnd should be similar to what you use to run the tests locally.
      # For e.g. assuming you run your tests locally using command "node YOUR_TEST_FILENAME.js.", enter the same command below:
      - npm run ios

  # The post test phase includes commands that are run after your tests are executed.
  post_test:
    commands:

# The artifacts phase lets you specify the location where your tests logs, device logs will be stored.
# And also let you specify the location of your test logs and artifacts which you want to be collected by Device Farm.
# These logs and artifacts will be available through ListArtifacts API in Device Farm.
artifacts:
  # By default, Device Farm will collect your artifacts from following directories
  - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share run url of the iOS runs?

Also can you give a try with empty capabilities i.e.

```
const awsopts = {
                 path: '/wd/hub',
                 port: 4723,
                 capabilities: {
                  },
                 };
```

as the device farm platform already sets the same as default-capabilities in pre_test phase.